# Spark orc reading string as decimal value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading orc file with following data

---

### | C1  |  C2    |

### | 1   | 1954E7 |

My column c1 should be int and c2 should be string but spark is interpreting the c2 as decimal. I tried following code to overcome it

`spark.read.option("inferSchema","false").option("header", "true").orc("path to file")`

But spark orc reader still reads the data with schema even though I force it to turn off the inferschema. Is there a way to force spark not to read the schema and I apply my custom schema later after the read?

Comment: try add format("orc") or use spark.read.option("header", "true").orc("path to file")

Comment: @mvasyliv thanks for correcting, I was actually doing the same and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession}

// spark: SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
```

when C2 is string

```
val pathORC =
  "<path>/source.orc"

case class O(C1: Int, C2: String)
val source = Seq(O(1, "1954E7")).toDF()

source.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: integer (nullable = false)
//    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)

source.show(false)
//    +---+------+
//    |C1 |C2    |
//    +---+------+
//    |1  |1954E7|
//    +---+------+

source.write.mode("overwrite").orc(pathORC)
val res = spark.read.orc(pathORC)
res.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: integer (nullable = true)
//    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)

res.show(false)
//    +---+------+
//    |C1 |C2    |
//    +---+------+
//    |1  |1954E7|
//    +---+------+
```

when C2 ???

```
val pathORC1 =
  "<path>/source1.orc"

val source1 = Seq((1, 1954e7)).toDF("C1", "C2")
source1.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: integer (nullable = false)
//    |-- C2: double (nullable = false)

source1.show(false)
//    +---+--------+
//    |C1 |C2      |
//    +---+--------+
//    |1  |1.954E10|
//    +---+--------+

source1.write.mode("overwrite").orc(pathORC1)
val res1 = spark.read.orc(pathORC1)
res1.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: integer (nullable = true)
//    |-- C2: double (nullable = true)

res1.show(false)
//    +---+--------+
//    |C1 |C2      |
//    +---+--------+
//    |1  |1.954E10|
//    +---+--------+

val dToStr = udf( (v: Double) => { v.toString.replace(".", "") } )
val res2 = res1
  .withColumn("C2", dToStr(col("C2")))

res2.printSchema()
//    root
//    |-- C1: integer (nullable = true)
//    |-- C2: string (nullable = true)

res2.show(false)
//    +---+-------+
//    |C1 |C2     |
//    +---+-------+
//    |1  |1954E10|
//    +---+-------+
```

Comment: in the example 2 when you have 1954e7 as C2 I am looking for it to remain same but in your case it has changed to 1954E10 when it became string. That's the problem I am chasing...

Comment: yes. I show moment when C2 is not string.